# phpstorm color scheme for sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, phpstorm, color-scheme

I had been using phpstorm for long time, now I am also working in sublime as its good for quick edits and best in sense of speed.

I want default color scheme of phpstorm in sublime. Is that already built ? OR How can I start with creating such color scheme ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Darcula, you can install it via package control.
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Darkula%20Color%20Scheme

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried here?

preferences >

or command + n (alt+n)

[image: sublime color themes]

Comment: I want default color scheme of phpstorm in sublime editor. Thanks for reply but IDLE is not default color scheme of phpstorm.