# Whats the name of these sublime text theme

Tags: themes, sublimetext

Can anybody tell me the name of the shown sublime text theme? Searched for it on google, with no luck. Or is is not sublime? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: That looks like it might be WebStorm and not Sublime.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for the hint. Didn't knew WebStorm yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Gavin, that seems to be the `WebStorm IDE`.

Based on [phpstorm color scheme for sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067425/phpstorm-color-scheme-for-sublime) answer, for `Sublime Text` there is the theme [Darkula Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Darkula%20Color%20Scheme), which seems to be `WebStorm IDE`'s `Sublime Text` theme version.